# Rails app not appear at a server's IP (just a blank page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, unicorn, production-environment

I have stucked with production server. Already trying to resolve it for 2 days but do not understand why it happens like this.
The problem is:
I have tried to deploy Rails application with nginx/unicorn/capistrano. Finally, I got the process working. Nginx and unicorn seem ok on my production server, but when I enter to my server's IP, there is just a blank screen. Before I had there at least a message that nginx is runned. I suppose that the problem may be that nginx and unicorn are searching the app in a wrong place, but I checked the routes and they seem correct.
The application has a root welcome page, so it should be displayed there...

Could you help me with your thougts what might be a problem?

P.S. if I create a test rails app at server and run it using webricks, is showed at MY_SERVER_IP:3000, so the problem is definetly with unicorn/nginx.

My nginx.conf file:

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.foreignernetwork.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    server_name justforeign.com;
    root /var/www/foreignernetwork/current/public;

location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;

}
```

My unicorn.rb file:

```
root = "/var/www/foreignernetwork/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.foreignernetwork.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

Comment: Just checked Unicorn log file - it chashes when thying to use a wrong Ruby version...

Comment: I have checked: **bundle exec ruby -v** it showed me that I use ruby version 2.2.2 and **bundle exec which unicorn** showed that I use 2.2.0, i think this is the problem

Comment: Is the process actually running?

Try `ps -ef | grep unicorn`. Nginx and unicorn should be set up using unix domain sockets.

The blank page may indicate nginx  is properly setup but the unicorn proces just isn't running.

If you like I've written detailed guide on deploying rails applications with nginx+unicorn.

https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/1-setup.md
https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/2-deploy-setup.md
https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/3-app-deploy.md

Comment: You're welcome, hope it help!

Comment: @JensD I was going with your guide and have caught an issue which can not resolve, please could you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202012/rbenv-version-2-2-2-is-not-installed-although-is-global-on-the-server-capistran

Comment: Glad you could fix your own problem. I was just looking into it, when I saw your own comment ;)

Comment: Now I have a problem - nginx server is run, but showes me only a welcome page on my server's IP address. The deploy has finished successfully, but I think there is something wrong with nginx setup...

Comment: Did you follow all 3 guides ? In one of the guides I override the default nginx.conf which allows multiple sites and virtual servers to be configured. It may be that your nginx server isn't properly configured to proxy towards the rails socket running under `/tmp/appname_unicorn.sock`

Comment: yes, I follow them and now have a problem with Unicorn restart:         INFO [7c7add6f] Running /usr/bin/env service unicorn_foreignernetwork restart as deployuser@[IP]
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployuser@justforeign.com: service unicorn_foreignernetwork restart exit status: 1

Comment: it shows a problem in the /etc/init.d/unicorn_... file in this part: test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`. I think i can be connected with the **:unicorn_pid** in the unicorn.rb.erb as i did not find a place where it initiates. Can this variable be missing?

Comment: the unicorn can't be started: deployuser@justforeign:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_foreignernetwork start
/etc/init.d/unicorn_foreignernetwork: line 25: kill: (10813) - No such process
master failed to start, check stderr log for details

Comment: @JensD as I see the unicorn can't started - there are such messages in the unicorn errors log file: adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.foreignernetwork.sock (in use)
something is conflicting, did you face something similar? Please could you help me?

Comment: Could you try removing the `/tmp/unicorn.foreignernetwork.sock` .
Kill the unicorn process by `ps -ef` look at the unicorn master process PID. Use `kill -9 [PID]`.
Afterwards make sure the user you are deploying with is a non root user with sudo rights available over ssh.

Try to deploy it again and see what happens. Something may have gotten messed up.

Comment: Ohhh you are a genius, dude... Brilliant! But I have another problem... everything got back and I have a blank page :)

Comment: I have checked my ruby versions (ruby -v, and they are 2.2.2 (rbenv versions shows that is an only verson)), but... in the shared folder I have version 2.2.0:      /var/www/foreignernetwork/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn          rbenv which ruby shows /home/deployuser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby

Comment: bundle exec which unicorn shows     /var/www/foreignernetwork/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn
  facepalm...                                    and there is only one 2.2.2 in the ~/.rbenv/versions

Comment: even if I remove it, everytime sets up ruby 2.2.0 and unicorn is using this Ruby, although is not installed at both server and my laptop either... checking more..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77847/discussion-between-neon-10-and-jensd).

Comment: there was also a problem with missing secret token. Uffff, now everything is working! :D thank you a lot! And I started understand how do all this work.